# Display max value rows only

Tags: sql-server, max

I have the following table (must shorter version than the real one),
and I want to all the rows with max **_ values for each _** displayed.
How should I do this?

Table Now

[image]

Table I want to have

[image]

thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Don't use images for sample data and what have you tried? This doesn't look particularly difficult if you use a window function like `RANK()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `dense_rank` function and a derived table would be appropriate for this (please note I used underscores instead of spaces in the column names):

```
select group_type
       ,desk_number
       ,comments
from
(select *
       ,dense_rank() over(partition by group_type order by desk_number desc) dr
from mytable) t1
where t1.dr = 1
```

I made a rextester sample that you can try [here](http://rextester.com/LKDWS70116)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(DeskNumber AS INT) DESC PARTITION BY GroupType),
    GroupType,
    DeskNumber,
    [Comment]
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
*
FROM CTE WHERE CTE.SeqNo = 1
```

Comment: the `JOIN` is useless

Comment: You Can use Exists instead. I wrote just one method.

Comment: No, it does not make a sense to do the self join and also exists is useless. Just remove the `JOIN` and you will have basicaly the same solution as @Simon

Answer (score 0):

[How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql?rq=1)

This answers your question quite well but I will convert it for your convenience <3

```
SELECT *
FROM table
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT comments, MAX([desk number]) AS MaxDesk
    FROM table
    GROUP BY comments) groupedtable
ON table.[desk number]= groupedtable.[desk number]
AND table.comments= groupedtable.MaxDesk
```